Join with distinct PostgreSQL
I have two tables. Both contain the columns order_ (integer), id_ (UUID), and text_ (text). The tobe table has the correct order_ values while the asis table has incorrect order_ values for the same id_.
INSERT INTO tobe (order_,id_,text_) VALUES
 (10,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (11,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (12,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (13,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (14,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (15,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','');

INSERT INTO asis (order_,id_,text_) VALUES
 (7,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (8,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (9,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (10,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (11,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970',''),
 (12,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','');

I need to get table with correct order_ from tobe table, id_, text_ and wrong order_ from asis table = 6 rows.
If I will join it by id_, I get 36 rows, 6 for each order
But I need smth like this
 (order_tobe, id_, text_, order_asis)
 (10,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','', 7),
 (11,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','', 8),
 (12,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','', 9),
 (13,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','', 10),
 (14,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','', 11),
 (15,'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','', 12);


Please share the JOIN query you are trying to perform.

What is the condition for joining the rows? That the first row in asis as ordered by ordered_ is joined with the first row in tobe as ordered by order_, and so on? There's not enough data in the columns to do this. But you can probably use window functions (ie ROW_NUMBER() to achieve what you want.

@johnnyaug SELECT distinct on(t.rwnmbr) t.rwnmbr, t.lib_action_id, t.task_action_text, a.rwnmbr
FROM tobe as t
JOIN asis as a ON t.lib_action_id = a.lib_action_id
ORDER BY t.rwnmbr;

@Dunes tobe.lib_action_id = asis.lib_action_id yes, I see that there is not enough column, but I suppose there may do something

would  ([10,11,12,13,14,15],'22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970','',[7,8,9,10,11,12]) be a solution, too? Then two array_agg(DISTINCT ...) could be your friend

You can use row_number() (a window function) to give each of the rows in each table a number. You can then join using this synthetic number column and the id_ column. We use PARTITION BY so that the row number starts over for each column that window function is to be partitioned by. We also ORDER BY the window function as you wanted to join the row with smallest order_ value in tobe with the smallest order_ value in asis for the same value of id_, and so on for the second smallest values of order_.
We do a FULL OUTER JOIN so that if there are an unequal number of rows with the same id_ in the tables then these rows that cannot be paired with another show up.
WITH asis_numbered AS (
        SELECT
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_ ORDER BY order_) AS row_number,
        id_,
        order_ AS asis_order,
        text_ AS asis_text
        FROM asis
), tobe_numbered AS (
        SELECT
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_ ORDER BY order_) AS row_number,
        id_,
        order_ AS tobe_order,
        text_ AS tobe_text
        FROM tobe
)
SELECT * FROM tobe_numbered
FULL OUTER JOIN asis_numbered USING (id_, row_number)
ORDER BY id_, row_number;

This will output something like:
                 id_                  | row_number | tobe_order | tobe_text | asis_order | asis_text
--------------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------
 22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970 |          1 |         10 |           |          7 |
 22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970 |          2 |         11 |           |          8 |
 22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970 |          3 |         12 |           |          9 |
 22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970 |          4 |         13 |           |         10 |
 22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970 |          5 |         14 |           |         11 |
 22b48906-4d7f-4d22-a027-101d0a96b970 |          6 |         15 |           |         12 |
 different-group                      |          1 |          9 |           |            |
(7 rows)

I added a second id_ value (different-group) to only one of the tables. We can see that it still shows up, despite only being present in one table. We can also see that it is not mixed in with your other id_ value (thanks to the PARTITION BY clause), and that the row number starts again at 1. Using the tobe_order and asis_order columns, it is possible to identify which table contains this orphaned row.
